# why my streamBuilder get stuck in the active Connection State even though i got all the data in my App?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Im getting data in my Flutter Web App from my Firebase Collection but my stream builder connection state **stuck in the active state** and not proceeding to the done state

```
  static Stream<QuerySnapshot> getData({required String collectionName}) {
    return firebaseFirestore.collection(collectionName).snapshots();
  }
```

this is how im calling the stream

```
  late final Stream<QuerySnapshot> myStream;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myStream = FireStoreServices.getData(collectionName: selectedRadio!);
  }
```

my build method

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: myStream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
              return const Center(
                child: Text('No Data'),
              );

            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
              // **stream stuck here** as long as the application is running even though i **got all the data**
            case ConnectionState.active:
              return const Center(
                child: Text('Connection is active'),
              );

            case ConnectionState.done:
              return const Center(
                child: Text('Connection is DOne'),
              );
            default:
              return const Center(
                child: Text(' default state '),
              );
          }
```

**Any Help Would be Appreciated**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal when you use StreamBuilder unlike FutureBuilder. Actually you should display data while the state is active or if the state is done.

Bellow a small example on how to use StreamBuilder:

```
  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active
      || snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return const Text('Error');
    } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text(
        snapshot.data.toString(),
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.teal, fontSize: 36)
      );
    } else {
      return const Text('Empty data');
    }
  } else {
    return Text('State: ${snapshot.connectionState}');
  }
```

You could find more info about StreamBuilder in this [blog.](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-streambuilder-widget-examples)

Comment: But the connectionstate is always in waiting state and it shows endless circular progress indicator.